# Can't use macro more than once in gVIM

Tags: vim

in gVim, I am trying to do

```
q 2 dd j q
```

Then

```
@2
```

at several points later.  It works the first time (meaning vim deletes three lines and moves down when I type `@2`), but anytime after that, my screen blinks and the cursor moves down once.

Is there a setting I need in vimrc or something to allow this macro?

Comment: I see the problem, but it seems to work for me when I use 'q' instead of '2' for the macro register...

Comment: @Stefan Mai hmmm me too.  Is using a number as the register incorrect or something?  I know it works on on my work machine, just not at home (but can't access my work machine to look at the config)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What is happening is that Vim uses the [*Numbered registers*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_number) to store recent changes made with the yank and delete commands. That will wipe your macro from the register.

As a general recommendation, avoid the numeric registers when recording macros.

Comment: +1 I stumbled on this problem recently as well, and it took some time to figure out using a number for the macro name caused the problem. Now I know why :)

Comment: Seems like every macro I record needs to save to a register...I wish there was a more convenient way to do it. The best one can hope for is 'macro best practices'. I couldn't find anything particular to the user of registers (which deserves attention, obviously!). But I'm in love with the tips at the Vim wiki, so, plug: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros